# Alter a view in EntityFramework CF with migration files

Tags: c#, sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

For our project, we are using the Entity Framework (Version 6) with the code first database. So, when we want to change a procedure or a table, we do that in a class and generate a Migration File to update the Database (simple `Update-Database` in the Paket-Manager window).

If we want to change something that didn't get a class (like a View or a procedure) we change the migration file, which will look like this as an example:

```
public override void Up()
{
  //Some other code... 

  Sql("ALTER VIEW ExampleView AS Select [Endless Lines of code]");
}
```

When it comes to bigger views, it gets very messy very fast.

**My Question is**

Is there a "smart" way to update small things in a procedure or maybe a view (like changing something in the `FROM` Statement) without creating a whole SQL statement that counts many rows just to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what would qualify as "smart", but you can remove the SQL statement clutter from your migration classes by putting them in separate files. This [article](http://laboremus.ug/?p=1708) explains how.

Comment: Yeah we moved away from that. Working with .sql files was our previous solution. And with smart I mean something maybe less messy.

Comment: I see, you're not the only one struggling with this. See  discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/827) on github

Comment: Interesting. Well, hopefully they will add view mapping soon. But thanks for that link. It shows some very interesting workarounds.